# Async Calls Catch 401 Errors Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

I have written a small application using React Native and TS. In my application I use authorization through `access_token`s with lifetime for one hour. Every time the token expires, I launch `refreshToken` function where I send access_token and refresh_token that were saved previously in local storage and send it through POST method.

basically something like this:

```
if (token_from_storage !== is_expired) {
    //assuming token is indeed in storage
    return access_token;
} else {
    //this Function calls an api with refresh token
    const { tokens }: { tokens: ITokens } = await refreshToken(refresh_token);
    saveTokens(tokens); //here we save new access_token and refresh_token
}
```

after `refreshToken` has finished the new tokens are saved locally (and were updated on DB level) and must be used if you want refresh tokens again.

For example, we launch an application with an expired token. The methods on the start will be `getUserInfo()` and `getApplicationInfo()` that get some important data. They are launched through redux-saga or something similar (async).

```
//first app screen
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(ACTION_GET_USER_INFO);
   dispatch(ACTION_GET_APPLICATION_INFO);
},[])
```

first method would launch `refresh_token` about the same time as the second one. The tokens will be rebuilt for the first method and update on the database level. By the time second method calls `refreshToken` (he was launched at the same time; he also thinks that the token is dead), the refresh_token will be changed on DB level and would not answer 200 on the `refreshToken()` call.

What should be done to achieve proper refreshing?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your issue correctly it sounds like you are calling two async function that both refresh tokens if the current token has expired.

This indicates you are experiencing a race condition in your useEffect statement, and because the requests handle refreshing their token independently at least one of the request will have an invalid token.

Personally, I would not being handling tokens in the client at all especially with local storage.

If you must however, you can fix the race condition by adding a service layer that handles requests, and tokens singularly. Your dispatch functions will pass through the service layer which can determine the need to refresh a token and if a token is being refreshed already in a synchronous manner before attempting to send the requests.

Comment: I was thinking the same way: implementing a layer before calling refreshToken and checking whether the refresh process is started.
the question is then: what do to do with the call if the refresh process is started. how do we wait and get the new tokens?

Comment: You could accomplish that in a variety of ways, a simple solution would be to add a flag that indicates a refresh is taking place in your service layer, and have a while loop that checks that flag and maybe waits X amount of time.  Again, I believe that your backend should be issuing and handling your tokens and your client should be redirecting the user to authenticate themselves again with a 401.

Comment: Backend is handling all processes indeed. My problem was that I have dispatches that start in parallel. And both of them might call a method to api at the same time that might return either 200 or 401. Hence I was trying to limit the number of calls and clear server load.